# SQLAlchemy DetachedInstanceError when Unit testing with Flask app.test_client

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, python-unittest

My goal is to be able to test routes with the Flask app test_client using `self.client.post(url, ...`. The problem that I'm running into is any time I make a request using it, I hit a DetachedInstanceError from SQLAlchemy, saying that either refresh or lazy loading operations cannot occur.

Here's my setup:

```
class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

   def setUp(self):
      self.postgresql = Postgresql()
      config = {
         'FLASK_ENV': 'test',
         'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI': self.postgresql.url()
      }
      with patch.dict('os.environ', config):
         self.app = create_app()
         self.client = self.app.test_client()
         ctx = self.app.app_context()
         ctx.push()
         db.create_all()
         self.assertEqual(app.testing, True)
      reset_fake_data()

   def tearDown(self):
      db.session.remove()
      self.postgresql.stop()

   def post(self, url, data={}, headers={}):
      headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', **headers}
      return self.client.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))

   def post_with_auth_token(self, url, data={}, headers={}):
      headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.auth_token}'}
      return self.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Then in another file, I'm calling this with `response = self.post('/api/users/register', data=data)` and getting the error:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance <User at 0x10ea43f98> is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'courses' cannot proceed (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/bhk3)
```

Below is the route. I create a user object and then attempt to add a course to it but apparently, when I try to do `user.courses.append`, it's unable to lazy load the courses. I've looked into disabling the `expire_on_commit` attribute, but I'm not sure how to do that only in the cases of testing, or if there's a better way to go about this.

I read that converting from lazy to eager loading could also fix it, but I'd rather keep things loading lazily and it didn't seem to fix it when I set the relationship to be `lazy='subquery'` anyways.

```py
@users.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register():
   data = request.get_json()
   try:
      user = User.from_data(**data)
   except UnprocessableEntity:
      return jsonify(msg='Missing parameters'), 422
   except Conflict:
      return jsonify(msg='Email already exists'), 409
   except Unauthorized:
      return jsonify(msg='Unauthorized'), 401
   if data.get('invitation_token'):
      invite = CourseInvite.query.filter_by(token=data['invitation_token']).first_or_404('Invite not found')
      if invite.email and invite.email != user.email:
         return jsonify(msg='Email mismatch'), 401
      elif invite.used:
         return jsonify(msg='Invite already used'), 401
      user.courses.append(CourseEnrollment(course_id=invite.course.id))
      invite.used = True
   db.session.add(user)
   db.session.commit()
   return jsonify(msg='User successfully created'), 201
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Gustavo_fringe not yet - I'll update if I figure it out.

Comment: For those who come along later: I was having a similar issue and realized the problem was that I was referencing the object outside of the session where it was committed. To get around this, I changed my code to store the primary key of the object while the session was still open and then queried that key later to get and delete the row.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        self.postgresql = Postgresql()
        config = {
            'FLASK_ENV': 'test',
            'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI': self.postgresql.url()
        }
        with patch.dict('os.environ', config):
            self.app = create_app()
            self.client = self.app.test_client()
            self.app.app_context().push()

    def setUp(self):
        with self.app.app_context():
            db.create_all()
            self.assertEqual(app.testing, True)
        reset_fake_data()

    def tearDown(self):
        with self.app.app_context():
            db.session.remove()
            self.postgresql.stop()

    def post(self, url, data={}, headers={}):
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', **headers}
        return self.client.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))

    def post_with_auth_token(self, url, data={}, headers={}):
        headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.auth_token}'}
        return self.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```